# Is it usual to declare the arguments in a function prototype?

Tags: c, arguments, prototype

I know that it is possible to declare function prototypes without arguments. And I'm not seeing any benefit in using them in my codes.

Are there any popular recommendations regarding the use of arguments in the function prototype?

Comment: Might be useful to clarify which language you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry... Im using C

Comment: You should clarify your terminology. In the 2018 C standard, 6.2.1 2 says “A *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.” So `void foo();` is not a function prototype at all. `void foo(int, char);` is a function prototype. And `void foo(int x, char y);` is a prototype that includes names of parameters, which largely have no effect, so they serve primarily as documentation for humans. And those are declarations of parameters, not arguments. Per C 2018 3.3, an argument is what is passed to a function, not what is declared in its declaration.

Comment: It helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of declaring a function with a prototype is to specify the types of its parameters. This allows the compiler to check for some errors in function calls, such as mistakenly passing a pointer to one structure type when a pointer to some other kind of object was declared for the function parameter. Catching errors as early as possible is an important part of software engineering.

A minor benefit is converting the arguments to the parameter types. For example, suppose a function `foo` is defined with a `double` parameter in its source code. If the declaration visible in the header file is `void foo();`, and we want to pass it a `k` that is an `int`, then we have to write `foo((double) k)` or equivalent. However, if the visible declaration is `void foo(double);`, then we can write `foo(k)`, and `k` will be automatically converted to `double`.

Note the terminology used in the C standard:

A *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters, per C 2018 6.2.1 2. The C standard currently allows function declarations without parameter types, such as:

```
void foo(); // Says nothing about what the parameters are.
```

or with parameter types, such as:

```
void foo(int, char); // Says the function has an `int` parameter and a `char` parameter.
```

A function prototype can also include names for the parameters:

```
void foo(int x, char y);
```

In a function declaration that is not a definition (does not provide the body of the function), parameter names are useful for little more than giving human readers clues about what the parameters are for. In a function definition, the names are needed so the parameters can be referred to inside the function.

Also, the C standard uses *argument* to mean an expression that is passed to a function in a function call, as defined in C 2018 3.3. A *parameter* is the function’s copy of the argument value, as defined in C 2018 3.16.

Comment: `void foo(); // Says nothing about what the parameters are.` --> Is not this to change with C23?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is possible to declare function prototypes without arguments.

If you are still living in the seventies.

The original C compilers were rudimentary contraptions, famous for being able to successfully compile pretty much any text you threw at them; the runtime results you would get were a totally different story. Segfault, mostly.

Once the language became popular, compilers started supporting this wonderful feature called ***warnings***. Compiler vendors were still insecure about them, so they were not enabled by default, but at least you could enable them if you knew the right <strike>magical-incantations</strike> compiler command-line arguments.

Back in the 90s when I was at the University we were trying to program in ANSI C without warnings, because our professors never told us anything about the benefits of warnings, or how to enable them. After the University, at work, I remember colleagues writing code in C without warnings enabled, because they believed they knew better than the compiler. This would give rise to monstrous bugs like this: [michael.gr - The Mother of All Bugs](https://blog.michael.gr/2015/10/the-mother-of-all-bugs.html)

Our profession has advanced considerably since then. Warnings are considered beneficial. No, you do not know better than the compiler. You are a human. You make mistakes. It is a given fact. Enable all warnings that the compiler has to offer to you.

If you have all warnings enabled, then the compiler will not allow you to omit the arguments.

Comment: A prototype is, by definition, a function declaration that includes the types of its parameters. `void foo();` is a function declaration that is not a prototype. C 2018 6.2.1 2 says “A *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil okay, but I am not sure what you are suggesting should change in my answer.

Comment: If you have all warnings enabled, then declaring `void foo();` will only allow you to invoke `foo()` without any parameters, so it ***does***, in a sense, play the role of a prototype.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There, maybe now you will be happy.  (In the first sentence, I am just echoing the OP's statement.)

Comment: @MikeNakis *If you have all warnings enabled, then declaring `void foo();` will only allow you to invoke foo() without any parameters, so it **does**, in a sense, play the role of a prototype*  What compiler?  Pre-C23, given the declaration `void foo()`, there's no difference in calling `foo();` or `int x; foo(x);` or `double d; foo(d);` - they should either **all** generate warnings, or none of them should generate warnings.

Comment: (cont) [6.7.6.3p14](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p14): "The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied."  So any compiler should treat all call to a function declared with `void foo()` in exactly the same way, parameter or no parameters.  In C23, `void foo();` is identical to `void foo(void);` a function that takes *no* parameters

Comment: @AndrewHenle oh, I forgot about that. You see, I moved on to C++ early on. But you are right. Now, since that wrong statement is in a comment, I cannot edit it. I could delete the comment, but then your comments will not make sense. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Also, I assume that if you have all warnings enabled, then the compiler will give you a warning if you declare `foo()` instead of `foo(void)`, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the point of declaring your functions. A function declaration (prototype) is supposed to describe what the function does (with a good name) and what it needs to do that thing (arguments), without the need to look at the actual code inside of a function.

If we are speaking about C you can't really declare a function without declaring its arguments (if there are some) unless you're talking about variadic args which is a very niche topic.

Comment: C (at least until the next version of the standard is issued) does let you declare a function with declaring its parameters (not arguments). `void foo();` is a valid declaration of a function that says nothing about its parameters. The definition of a function needs to declare its parameters, if it has any, but that is another matter.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh I thought it works the same as in C++, now I have the exact opposite of the original question: what's the point of declaring a function and not specifying the arguments? :D

Comment: Function declarations that are not prototypes are holdovers from early C code, before the modern syntax for declaring function parameter types was created. They should not be written in new code.

Answer (score 0):

The most important one is to tell the compiler what is the return type of the function and what type of arguments it is taking. If you do not do this the compiler will think that they have the `int` type and it may lead to the Undefined Behaviour. Generally **always** use function prototypes.